# Custom button to set custom order status

Tags: magento-1.9, module, order-status

I created a custom module to add a button to the order view page.

The button shows up and now it is time to create the action attached. When clicking the button I want 2 things to happen:

Set the order status to: Ready for Pickup (pickup_ready) which I defined in order statusses
Send a transactional email to the client to inform them it is ready

My button looks like this for now:

```
{
public function  __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

        $this->_addButton('inform_pickup', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Custom Pickup Button'),
            'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getPickupUrl() . '\')',
        ));
    }

public function getPickupUrl()
{
    Not a clue what to put here......;
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: in which file did you added this code?

Comment: I have this code under app/code/local/MyModule/Pickup/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/View.php

Answer (score 0):

**In construct function you will need to pass order object in your**

```
public function  __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    $order = $this->getOrder();

        $this->_addButton('inform_pickup', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Custom Pickup Button'),
            'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getPickupUrl($order) . '\')',
        ));
    }
```

**You will need to create your controller to handle the action**

```
public function getPickupUrl($order)
{
   return $this->getUrl('your_adminhtml_controller_action', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
}
```

**In your controller class create your action for example**

```
public function pickupAction()
{
  $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
  $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
  $order->setStatus("pickup_ready");
  $order->save();
  // redirect to your sales order view page back
}
```

Comment: Ok, I assume that would be a new file located in app/code/local/MyModule/Pickup/controllers/action.php?

Comment: yes you will need to create controller class MyModule/Pickup/controllers/ like IndexController.php

Comment: Almost there, sorry for the amount of ignorance from my side. I now created the file /Mymodule/Pickup/controllers/Action.php and in the getPickupUrl($order) I have return $this->getUrl('Mymodule_Pickup_controller_Action', array('order_id' => $order->getId())); Now if I click the button I am redirected to the frontend 404

Comment: you are doing it in wrong way. it should be like $this->getUrl('yourrouter/adminhtml_yourcontroller/youraction', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));

Comment: Not sure I know what to make of that in my case. What should be in yourrouter yourcontroller youraction?

Answer (score -1):

**admin side:**

```
public function  __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

        $this->_addButton('inform_pickup', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Custom Pickup Button'),
            'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getPickupUrl($order) . '\')',
        ));
}

public function getPickupUrl($order)
{
   return $this->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
}
```

**Fronted side:**

```
public function getPickupUrl($order)
{
   return $this->getUrl('sales/order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
}
```

Comment: But this does not change the status of the order, or am I seeing it wrong?

Comment: can you add your module controller code in ques? Please add order status change code in your module

Comment: I was expecting something like this: (this does not work)     public function getPickupUrl()
    {
 return $this->setState('processing', 'pickup_ready', 'test', false);
 return $this->save();        
    }